# How to generate random values to plot a barchart in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

i'm using WPF chart controls downloaded from http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535

Here i'm trying to plot a barchart and this is my sample code

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    List<Institute> list = new List<Institute> {
        new Institute { Subject = "Computers", students = 122 },
        new Institute { Subject = "Physics", students = 170 },
        new Institute { Subject = "Maths", students = 210 },
        new Institute { Subject = "Chemistry", students = 1840 },
        new Institute { Subject = "Electronics", students = 140 },
        new Institute { Subject = "Economics", students = 20 },
        new Institute { Subject = "Science", students = 100 },
        new Institute { Subject = "Scocial", students = 110 },
        new Institute { Subject = "English", students = 120 },
        new Institute { Subject = "Biology", students = 130 },
        new Institute { Subject = "Zoology", students = 140 },
        new Institute { Subject = "Hindi", students = 150 }};

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ColumnSeries bs = mcChart.Series[0] as ColumnSeries;
        bs.ItemsSource = list;           
    }

}
public class Institute
{
    public string Subject
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public int students
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

XAML code is

```
<Window x:Class="net.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:DVC="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
xmlns:DV="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
Title="Window1" Height="800" Width="800" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit">
<Grid>
    <DVC:Chart Canvas.Top="80" Canvas.Left="10" Name="mcChart"
       Width="800" Height="450" FontSize="12"
       Background="DarkGray" Foreground="DarkRed">
        <DVC:Chart.Series>
            <DVC:ColumnSeries x:Name="Barchart" Title="Students of an institute"
        ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
        IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Subject}"
        DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=students}" >
                <DVC:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DVC:ColumnDataPoint">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#001100"/>                          
                    </Style>
                </DVC:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle>
            </DVC:ColumnSeries>               
        </DVC:Chart.Series>
    </DVC:Chart>
</Grid>
```

With this code i can plot the chart but i need to plot it dynamically.

When ever i'm running this code i need generate random number of students(using Random) for each and every subject continuously and graph should be plotted based on the new values.
That means i want to see the dynamic changes in that graph on the GUI

Is it possible?

If it is possible please answer this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) to this. When ever your collection is modified, raise an event `CollectionChanged` and your chart will get rebind. Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748365.aspx) example from MSDN or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450582/observablecollection-tutorial).

Hope this works for you.